I want to save the snapshot settings of all the resources on AWS for change management and enable rollback of resource configuration to desired state
I want to save the snapshot settings of all the resources on AWS for change management and enable rollback of resource configuration to desired state
This is required for the audit purpose on our AWS account to see un announced changes and rollback to the previous state if required. Is there a way we can rollback automatically?
This requirement should be applicable for all the resources on AWS
I tried to get the resource snapshot from AWS config and stored it to S3 bucket. But this wrote the Configuration related to AWS config service itself, not actual resource snapshots.
I am confused whether to use cloudtrail or aws config to see the events and changes

There is no capability to "snapshot settings of all resources on AWS". Each AWS service would have its own way of listing resources. If you want to be able to "roll-back", then you should be deploying resources through templates, using either AWS CloudFormation or Terraform. This way, the infrastructure is created from scripts and you can roll-back to previous versions of the scripts. This is much better than starting with the resources already deployed and then trying to 'capture' them in some way. You might want to look at https://former2.com/, but it won't suit all your needs.

But I was exploring the "aws config" service where we can see the delta for the configuration. From this information, can I get the existing configuration for all the resources across account?
Basically my requirement is to :

collect the existing snapshot of all resource configuration.
Evaluate the changes that have occurred (May be via some kind of notification system)
Rollback to the desired configuration if needed


AWS Config captures some information about a specific set of services, but not "all resources in AWS" and certainly nothing about what is 'inside' your EC2 instances. AWS CloudTrail captures the API calls made to AWS Services, showing what AWS was requested to do, but not the actual configuration of any resources.
